# Menu drops too far in mobile mode

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive site, however, one of my divs is preventing the mobile view from displaying properly. When the navigation is clicked, the menu jumps too far down due to a top margin property of 102px. I need this margin set this way when the navigation is closed, but not when it's open. I think the only way to make this responsive site work is using jquery to fix the problem, but so far each technique I try doesn't have an effect. I'm still very new to Jquery, so I'm not sure what to do. Any help is very appreciated. Thanks.

JQUERY

```
var screensize = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

$(document).ready(function(){

    // check for window size size on page load and show relevant content only   
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        console.log(width);
        if (width < 600) {
            $('.link').hide();
        } else {
            $('.link').show();
        }
    });

    $('header').on('click', function() {
        $('.link').slideToggle(500);
        $('#G').css({'margin-top', '0'});
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/td5n8ky9/17) - just resize the browser for the mobile view. I just want to decrease the amount of margin when the header is clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide us with a JSFiddle so we can see the structure of the page and how it works? Without that however, one thing I can suggest is checking for the navigation, and apply or removing css attributes if it is visible or not.

For example:

```
if ($('.link').is(":visible")) {
    // Apply css changes needed if nav is visible   
} else {
  // Apply css changes needed if nav is not visible   
}
```

Looking at your code (without seeing it in its entirety), I imagine something like:

```
if ($('.link').is(":visible")) {
    $('#G').css('margin-top', '0'); // Remove margin if nav is visible  
}
```

Also, as an additional bit of info, the curly braces are not needed within your .css call, take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more info on the use of .css()

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/q4mxt9od/

Comment: When I try to input this code. I get a syntax error (specifically, when $('#G').css({'margin-top', '0'}); is added. I've completed the else statement, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. What am I missing? https://jsfiddle.net/td5n8ky9/18/

Comment: The {} are not needed around the css, I updated my answer. In fact, that's probably why you were not getting the results you were looking for in the first place

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I have deleted the {}. I'm currently experimenting with where to add the code so it takes effect - the 'if' statement works, but the 'else' statement doesn't seem to https://jsfiddle.net/td5n8ky9/19/

Comment: The other problem I get is once the browser is resized, the margin must be returned to 0px. I believe I need to add it to the top part of the code ($window).resize(function (() {, but since the .link class is visible when the browser resizes, it puts the margin into effect. Perhaps this is too complex - is there another method to get the result I'm searching for?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed response. I updated my answer with a JSFiddle that has a working solution. What I've done is use the window resize function you already had and made a call to a new function (the headerMargin function) every time the page was resized and it adjusts margins accordingly every time the window resizes. Let me know if that helps

Comment: That's okay, I'm pretty late with responding now as well. I've looked at the fiddle and have tried to get it and it does work, but when I resize the screen to desktop view I get a top-margin on the #G graphic. I've been trying to rework the code and make it more efficient, here's a fiddle I've done for the update: http://jsfiddle.net/td5n8ky9/22/, I think the code is a bit better in this one, but I'm still fighting with the margin.